# How can i get display column value in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image: This is output window]

This is the output of the query "select * from FindNthHighestNumber order by ProductAmount desc"

I want the individual value of bordered green portion of the above image. How can i do that? something like row = '2'

Comment: are you using `ORDER BY`?

Answer (score 0):

```
Select *,Row_number(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) from  Table
```

Comment: This doesn't mean that the results are in the same order than the `row_number`

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you want:

```
select f.*, row_number() over (order by f.ProductAmount desc)
from FindNthHighestNumber f
order by f.ProductAmount desc;
```

If you just want the numbers, then remove the `f.*` from the `select`.  If you want to select a particular value, then one method is to use a subquery:

```
select f.*
from (select f.*, row_number() over (order by f.ProductAmount desc) as seqnum
      from FindNthHighestNumber f
     ) f
where seqnum = 2;
```

Or, if you just want the second row, then a better method is `offset`/`fetch`:

```
select f.*
from FindNthHighestNumber f
order by f.ProductAmount desc
offset 1
fetch first 1 row only;
```